# How to assign an expression to a variable and check if it is odd or even in Smarty Script

Tags: php, smarty

In smarty script I need to assign a random integer to a variable and display some content if that variable is odd or even.
I know I can get a random integer with

```
{math equation = rand(1,20)}
```

But how to assign it to a variable and check if it is odd or even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign to a variable in Smarty you can use

```
{$check=rand(1,20) nocache}
```

https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.builtin.functions.tpl#language.function.shortform.assign

To check if a variable is even you can use

```
{if $check is even}
   ...
{/if}
```

https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this {$check = rand(1,20)} doesn't work (output is empty), while this {math equation = rand(1,20)} works and I cannot understand why

Comment: Oh yes, Smarty. Could you try `{assign var=check value=1|rand:20}`? I'll edit my answer if this works

Comment: Just installed Smarty and `{$check=rand(1,20)}` seems to work too. I edited my answer to add `nocache` to it, so the value doesn't get cached